# Bash run gpxlogger on startup

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I am trying to get a gpxlogger running after booting up RaspPi, the problem is that gpxlogger automatically shuts down after 5 seconds if there is no signal from GPSD on startup (which gets the signal around 1,5-2 minutes after boot, sometimes more so sleep would probably not solve it), and if that happens, it returns with a 0.

So far I've got:

```
(while true; do
     until gpxlogger -d -f /home/pi/gpslogs/log'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'.txt -i 2; do
         echo "restarting"
         sleep 10
     done
done
) &
```

in /etc/init.d/rc.local

The problem is, the script doesn't wait for the gpxlogger to return, but starts a new gpxlogger every 10 seconds.

**tl;dr Desired action:**

Start up Raspberry -> Loop gpxloggers dying after 5 seconds of no data from GPSD -> Get fix in GPSD -> Single gpxlogger keeps logging into file

Could someone try to help me with this? 
Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't restart if it's already running.

```
while true; do
    if ! pidof gpxlogger >/dev/null; then
        echo "restarting"
        gpxlogger -d -f /home/pi/gpslogs/log'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'.txt -i 2
    fi
    sleep 10
done &
```

(The parentheses appear to be superfluous, so I removed them.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `%H` et al will be substituted with the current hour etc.  That's not a feature of the normal Unix shell; you probably want to interpolate `date` like `/home/pi/gpslogs/log$(date +%F-%T).txt`

Comment: The format I use seems to work fine on Raspbian- the files are named correctly, but thanks for the input.

Comment: Oh, maybe `gpxlogger` makes the substitution.

Comment: Quite possible- I found the date format on gpxlogger-related question on raspberry forums.